# Most effective terran rush in SC2

Tags: starcraft-terran, starcraft-2

So what's the fastest and most effective terran rush in SC2 ?

I tried building reapers fast, but most of the times I get owned, especially by zergs :s

Comment: Are you looking for all in rush or a rush that can be build on for something else

Comment: An all in rush :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Against Protoss, your best bet is the [1/1/1 all-in](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/1/1/1_Build/Banshee_into_Siege_Tech_All-in).

> **Overview**
>
> A Cloak Banshee opening into Siege Tank Reactor-Marine all-in was famous amongst Protoss known as errorously as the 1/1/1, this variation masses Marines and adds Siege Tanks and attacks when Siege Tank (2) finishes; usually around the 10 min mark; when Protoss are quick teching to Colossus.
>
> **Goal**
>
> Using Banshees to force a large amount of Stalkers, Terran then masses Marines with a few Siege Tanks to overwhelm the Stalker-heavy forces of Protoss.
>
> **Build Order**
>
> ```
> 10 - Supply Depot
> 12 - Refinery (1)
> 13 - Barracks
> 16 - Orbital Command + Factory
> 16 - Marine (1) + Supply Depot
> 20 - Starport + Hellion (1 only)
>          @100% Hellion (1) - Tech Lab (1) > Banshees (to 2) 
> 23 - Refinery (2) + Supply Depot
> 30 - Barracks > Reactor + Supply Depot
> 32 - Factory > Tech Lab (2)
> 39 - Siege Tanks + Supply Depot
> 52 - Siege Tech > @100% - Attack
> ```
>
> [**Read more here.**](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/1/1/1_Build/Banshee_into_Siege_Tech_All-in)

Answer (score 12):

A 6- or 3-Rax all-in rush is what you're looking for...simple, fast, cheap.

http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/6Rax_Allin

the 6-rax produces an obscene number of marines very early on, and while it does do damage to your own economy, you can transition if need be, should you do equivalent damage to your opponent.

http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/3_Rax_All_In

The 3-rax relies on using the supply depot drop-down as well as using scv's to tank damage, and therefore is the very definition of all-in...should you lose your push, there's no coming back.

Comment: TeamLiquid is a good soure for such information, these builds worked for me. +1

Answer (score 4):

Semi-mass Marine Marauder Medivac will be your best bet. Convert to really mass (200/200 supply) if game gets a little long.

You should have an army similar to this:

[image]

Comment: That's not really a "rush" with those tier-3 medivacs, though, is it?  You might have hit the head on "most effective", but not exactly the "fastest".

Comment: @Ketura: These units can be obtained by a pro in 10 - 12 minutes , for the average unpracticed player this will take like more like 12 - 20 minutes or so to obtain. 10 SD, 12 Ref, 14 Rax, 17 Fact, 18 SD, 20 Rax, 21 Star, 22 Ref, 22 Rax, 26 SD, 26 OC, 26 Rax Tech Lab, 33 Rax Tech Lab. But I agree, in its rush form it's nowhere near an optimal build and you are likely to lose the game in the meantime. Getting these units might however be a good transition out of an earlier rush like 3/6RaxAI, but was not what the OP asked...

Comment: Note though, that a pro might be able to pull something off with useful scouting which indicates that he could go for such build and if necessary just throw down defensive bunkers. Builds are meant as a guideline anyway, in the end you'll want to have a build that reacts to what your opponent does. Not something generic or specific that doesn't help when your opponent goes for certain builds.

Comment: certainly, certainly.  I think the purpose of most "build orders" is what to do with your time in the first 2-3 minutes or so where you don't have any relevant scouting information yet.  While what you do during this time usually won't hugely affect what happens later (see: orbital command opening), if you're going to rush, aiming for an early attack (like the 4:30 goal of the 3-rax) then you'll definitely have to mix your usual orders up.

Answer (score 1):

Something I've found to be fairly effective is a 2 reaper rush.Drop a tech lab before my first marine (assuming I've scouted their base already and know I won't get 6 pooled or something similar) and get 2 quick reapers. I don't train another reaper the whole rest of the game - that rax just trains marauders. A second rax goes up with reactor, and a third, fourth, etc... keep pumping up the rax. The two reapers, as soon as they're both up, go off to hit the opponent's mineral line. Best expected scenario, they were busy/slow to respond and you get 10 or 12. Certainly worth it, since you were going to pump marauders anyway. Typical scenario you get 5 or 6 before their army forces you back - still worth it in my books. Worst case you get spotted before you hit the mineral line. At this point you can hop back down, micro around (split them up if you need to) and scout their base. Might as well...

If I take out 7 or more workers with the 2 reaper rush, I can always get my expo up 2 or more minutes before my opponent. If they made it out alive (I never engage the army unless it's 1 zealot or 2 lings) then they can also go with my first push of 8-12 marine/marauder. It's not an immediate game winning rush, but it's fast and effective.

You're looking at something like

```
* 10 supply depot
* 12 rax
* 13ish gas (I kind of wing it, I'd have to do some math to determine optimal placement.)
* Tech Lab asap on rax
* 2 reapers asap on tech'd rax
```

Comment: I actually do something similar against protoss after another player pulled it on me...11 gas, 12 rax, 14 rax, then train three reapers (first reaper should finished just as the second tech lab finishes).  three reapers is enough to one-shot a worker, which I think is an acceptable reason to wait.  after raping their mineral line, go marauder and rush to thors.  works like a charm if I don't get dt rushed.

Comment: Dts are easily countered by a couple selectly placed missile turrets. :)

Comment: certainly, but it messes with the timing of the build, which does a pretty good job at baiting them into stalkers only to smash them with marauders/thors.